# How do I use advance Google search to sort image by most recent?

Tags: google-image-search

How do I use advance Google search to sort image by most recent? Google image search doesn't have options to sort by date.

Example: I would like to sort the following by most recent images:
 http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=isch:1&sa=1&q=wallpapers+for+desktop&aq=1&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=wall&start=0

Comment: If there's no setting for it, you may not be able to do it. Is there a Search API that might have that setting?

Comment: This doesn't sound programming related - if it is please clarify your question, otherwise you might be better off asking it at superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

**Correct**. Google Image search **does not have an option to sort or filter the search results by date.**

**Source**: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search

Specific Section:

Filter by image property

The Image Search supports the following restrictions:

- **Safesearch**: Turn Safesearch on or off
- **File type**: Return images of a specified file type
- **Rights**: Return only images with the specified license (for example, images labeled for commerical reuse) Image
- **size**: Return images of a specified size
- **Colorization**: Return images with specified colorization Color filter: Return images with that are dominantly of a specified color
- **Image type**: Return only images of a specified type (for example, show only clipart)

*(I understand this question does not belong on SO, but since I knew the answer, I figured might as well answer it :)*